# CannotResolveClassException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.ParallelSampler

Tags: gradle, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I ran into an issue which is basically that Gradle can not find the ParallelSampler class in which I included in my gradle file.

Basically, I am trying to use the plugin(**ParallelSampler**) developed by blazemeter in my project.

I am not sure why it is happening.

```
import org.ajoberstar.grgit.Grgit;

plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'groovy'
    id 'org.ajoberstar.grgit' version '4.0.0'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy-all', version: '2.4.16'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.10'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.jmeter', name: 'ApacheJMeter_core', version: '5.2.1'
    compile group: 'org.apache.jmeter', name: 'ApacheJMeter_http', version: '5.2.1'
    compile group: 'com.blazemeter', name: 'jmeter-parallel', version: '0.9'
}

task cloneJmeter() {
    doFirst {
        Grgit.clone {
            dir = "apache-jmeter/"
            uri = "https://github.com/apache/jmeter.git"
            remote = "origin"
            refToCheckout = "rel/v5.2.1"
        }
    }
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["src/"]

task copyJar(type: Copy) {
    from jar
    into "apache-jmeter/lib/"
}

clean.doFirst {
    delete "apache-jmeter"
}
```

I am seeing following console logs

```
Cause:
00:38:46  CannotResolveClassException: com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.ParallelSampler
00:38:46  
00:38:46   Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 
00:38:46  ---- Debugging information ----
00:38:46  cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
00:38:46  cause-message       : 
00:38:46  first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
00:38:46  class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
00:38:46  required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
00:38:46  converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
00:38:46  path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree[5]/hashTree[4]/com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.ParallelSampler
00:38:46  line number         : 242
00:38:46  version             : 5.2.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I want to download **jmeter-parallel** jar and store into **apache-jmer/lib/ext** of jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter Plugins need to go into **["lib/ext" folder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)** so if you put `jmeter-parallel-0.9.jar` file into "lib" folder JMeter won't recognize it as the plugin

Also be aware of [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) which provides possibility to install JMeter Plugins (**along with their dependencies)**, the Plugins Manager has [programmatic and command-line interfaces](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerAutomated/) so you should be able to use it for plugins installation from your Gradle build